# Java add a score counter

Tags: java, android

I have created a very simple java game, using different Textures.
I want to add a score counter/label on to that game, so that every time the player does something, the score increases.

I tried using Jlabel but I had troubles getting it to show. Maybe because I use Texture as a background.

I want it to be able to style the score label, where I can change the size and position.

Comment: This sounds pretty broad. Please show what code you're using, and describe the problem more.

Comment: The code is to much to show. basically i have created a game using java classes only. i want to run it on android phones. i have come to a platue because i dont know how to add a text with score counter on top right corner. is there any java code that gives you a text to top right corner of the game screen in android?

Comment: Then show a minimal example of the code that shows your problem.

Comment: could you just please give me some suggestion on what java code i could possibly use to have a text of some sort being shown in top right screen on android device.

Comment: `JLabel`?? Why is there an Android tag?

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 0):

> is there any java code that gives you a text to top right corner of the game screen in android

While you could do it in Java, Android doesn't use JLabel anyway.

You want XML.

Use a [`RelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) to align to parent-right/end and parent-top

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreCounter"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```